# Programmatically set ListPicker.selectedIndex in Nativescript + Angular App

Tags: angular, nativescript, listpicker

I am working on my first Nativescript App and I have chosen Angular for the framework. I've run into a little snag with a ListPicker component. I am able to render the component with a list of items and can initially set the selectedIndex; however, when I later try to change the selectedIndex programmatically (e.g. from 0 to 2) the value displayed in the UI does not update (testing on Android). Surprisingly, the selectedIndexChange callback does log the correct new selectedIndex. How do I force the UI to display the correct value for the new selectedIndex?

Comment: Hi @BikeBro - did you find a solution for this, i am facing the exact same problem?

Comment: It's been a while since I resolved this problem, but the solution was likely to set the selectedIndex in an ngZone callback.

Comment: @melund A lot of times running the statements that update the UI in a timeout fixes random issues of the UI not updating (this will automatically make it run in a ngZone).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ngZone.run` can be used to help force the UI to recognize a change in data:

```
import { NgZone } from "@angular/core";

export class TestComponent {

    selectedIndex: number;

    constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}

    testMethod(pos: number): void {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
            this.selectedIndex = pos;
        });
    }
}
```